# Software for manually enriching tabular data

Tags: data-analysis

I'm looking for a software tool to integrate into my data analysis workflow.

I work primarily in Python using pandas DataFrames, but halfway through the workflow I need to manually read each record and add some additional fields to the record based on that read.  For example, I might add a field that scores each record based on my read or I might add tags that relate to the subject matter.  After that enrichment is done, I continue through the workflow using Python.

Traditionally I have used Excel to do this; write the data frame to XLSX or a CSV, make my additions, and then read it back in with pandas.  But I continue to be dissatisfied with the approach.  There are some specific pain points (e.g., Excel crashes on me, I run into character encoding problems) but really I just feel like there should be a better way to do this.

I've thought about writing my own interface, but I would really like to avoid going down that route.  And it feels like this can’t be a unique use case.

The solution can be paid or open source, but I would prefer something that is well supported either commercially or from a community perspective.   I would also preferably be able to run on Windows, but I can do Linux, especially if I could run it over an x11 server.

Comment: Have you tried working with Spyder (https://github.com/spyder-ide)? Spyder has a variable explorer which allows you to view a dataframe as a table and manually edit it. I think Anaconda is the best way of getting python setup with spyder.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the suggestion.  I had used Spyder a long time ago when I first got into Python, but haven't for a while.  I didn't realize the dataframe explorer allowed you to edit it.  I suspect that its a little more rudementary than I would hope, but it could be an option, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: Pandas is awfully powerful. Perhaps diving deeper into its capabilities might help too.